# Understanding static methods in Java

Tags: java, static, static-methods

Can someone help me understand what does the following statement mean?

"Like any method, a static method can create or ***use named objects of its type***, so a static method is often used as a ***“shepherd” for a flock of instances of its own type***. "

Source: http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0037.shtml#Heading79

Comment: Frankly, a `static` method can create any number of instances of any type. Not sure what the author wants to say. You should probably ask this on that site itself

Comment: Ideally you should have left your question under comments on that website as i see there is a box to do so.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I agree. I don't see why StackOverflow should be treated as a validation site for arbitrary Internet junk.

Comment: Why do you have to be so rude and call that junk? Thousands of people read and learn from other websites and if they are learning the wrong thing they should be corrected (even if that requires the help of StackOverflow). Isn't that the whole point of StackExchange: Impart correct learning to everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: say you have a class `Person` that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    static ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        people.add(this);
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(name + ", age " + age);
    }

    public static void displayAll() {
        for (int i=0; i<people.size(); i++) {
            people.get(i).display();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, `people` belongs to the `Person` class itself because it is static, whereas `name` and `age` are non-static and belong to each `instance` of `Person`. Similarly, because `displayAll()` is static, it can only be called by `Person`, whereas the non-static `display()` can only be called by individual instances of `Person`.

To illustrate this, say you have this in your main class:

```
Person john = new Person("John", 25);
Person amy = new Person("Amy", 27);
System.out.println(john.name + " is " + john.age);
System.out.println(amy.name + " is " + amy.age);
```

This would create two instances of `Person`, `john` and `amy`, and would give the following output:

```
John is 25
Amy is 27
```

The following code would also work (assume for all examples from here on that `john` and `amy` have already been created as in the previous example):

```
john.display();
amy.display();
```

This would give this output:

```
John, age 25
Amy, age 27
```

Now, because `john` and `amy` are specific instances of `Person`, they cannot reference static variables or call static methods, so both of these next lines of code would be uncompilable:

```
System.out.println(john.people.size());
amy.displayAll();
```

However, the following would work:

```
System.out.println(Person.people.size());
Person.displayAll();
```

This would give this output:

```
2
John, age 25
Amy, age 27
```

However, the following would NOT work:

```
Person.display();
System.out.println(Person.name);
System.out.println(Person.age);
```

`Person.display()` does not work because `display()` is not a static method. The next two lines don't work because the variables `name` and `age` belong to specific instances of `Person` and do not apply to the `Person` class in general.

Comment: Thanks for the great example @Bethany Louise. That helped a lot! Just so that you know the `amy.displayAll();` worked but with warning. But that wasn't even what I was asking so that's completely fine. :) http://imgur.com/AsMPuGN